# Creating a custom XML from a hash table

Tags: xml, powershell

I have read some very interesting posts on the topic of my question in the past few weeks and have gotten close, but I need a very specific XML created from a hash table that i create by comparing a CSV to Active directory that outputs a csv with specific user data.
The specific fields are these: XrefCode, EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, BusinessEmail, StartDate.
The XML I need to have this data put in is extremely specific in format and I cannot find a way get this to work.
Here is the XML how it needs to end up like.
So it has to have a header of `<EmployeeImport>` at the top of the document and `</EmployeeImport>` at the bottom, as well as in the middle of the data `<ContactInformation>` and `</ContactInformation>`.

Here is a sample of the data i use, very basic.  My code reaches to AD and populates the email field.

Number  Display Name    Status  Location Ledger Code    Business Email  First Name  Last Name
1234567 Doe, John   Active  0GB50       John    Doe
2345678 Smith, Jane Active  0GB50       Jane    Smith

The hash table build looks like...

```
   $match = New-Object PSObject
            $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "XRefCode" $first.SamAccountName
            $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "EmployeeNumber" $first.SamAccountName
            $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "FirstName" $first.'First Name'
            $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "LastName" $first.'Last Name'
            $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "ContactInformationTypeXrefCode" 'BusinessEmail'
            $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "EffectiveStart" $TodaysDay
            $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "ElectronicAddress" $second.mail
            $combine += $match
```

The csv looks like the following: Sorry it doesn't line up well

```
XRefCode EmployeeNumber FirstName   LastName ContactInformationTypeXrefCode EffectiveStart  IsForSystemCommunication    ElectronicAddress
1234567    1234567       Joe          Doe      BusinessEmail         04/16/2021 0   Jdoe@Company.com
2345678    2345678       Jane        Smith     BusinessEmail    04/16/2021  0    Jsmith@Company.com
```

```
<EmployeeImport>
 <Employee>
  <XRefCode>1234567</XRefCode>
  <EmployeeNumber>1234567</EmployeeNumber>
  <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
  <LastName>Doe</LastName>
    <ContactInformation>
     <ContactInformationTypeXrefCode>BusinessEmail</ContactInformationTypeXrefCode>
     <EffectiveStart>2020-04-16</EffectiveStart>
     <ElectronicAddress>JoeDoe@Company.com</ElectronicAddress>
    </ContactInformation>
 </Employee>
 <Employee>
  <XRefCode>2345678</XRefCode>
  <EmployeeNumber>2345678</EmployeeNumber>
  <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
  <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <ContactInformation>
     <ContactInformationTypeXrefCode>BusinessEmail</ContactInformationTypeXrefCode>
     <EffectiveStart>2020-04-16</EffectiveStart>
     <ElectronicAddress>Jsmith@Company.com</ElectronicAddress>
    </ContactInformation>
 </Employee>
</EmployeeImport>
```

The code I found that was close was this...

```
$output |% {'<Objects>'} {$_.psobject.properties |% {'<Object>'} {"<$($_.name)>$($_.value)</$($_.name)>"} {'  </Object>'} } {'</Objects>'}
```

However, this doesn't add the header and footer needed as well as the middle Object between for the ContactInformation.

I might need to do this as custom for my case, but i'm not sure how to build this out.  If that's the case, could someone point me in the right direction to customize this for this specific case?

Thanks

Comment: And `$output` is a collection of objects that have `XrefCode`, `EmployeeNumber`, `FirstName`, ... etc. as properties?

Comment: Correct, right now the output is in a hash that is a csv with the needed headers.  I can give an example.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and code used to convert it to hashtable? so that anyone can reproduce and test you case.

Comment: Data added to the question

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating an `[xml]` document containing a `EmployeeImport` root-level element:

```
$xml = [xml]'<EmployeeImport/>'
$emplImport = $xml.DocumentElement
```

Now you'll want to add an `<Employee>` node to the root node for each input object:

```
$output = Import-Csv .\path\to\objects.csv

foreach($object in $output){
    # Create `<Employee>` node
    $employee = $emplImport.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement('Employee'))
    
    foreach($property in $object.psobject.Properties){
        # Create an xml child-element for each property on the input object
        $childNode = $employee.AppendChild($xml.CreateElement($property.Name))
        $childNode.InnerText = $property.Value
    }
}
```

And finally save the resulting xml document to disk:

```
# Important: only pass full/rooted paths to $xml.Save()
$outputPath = Resolve-Path .\path\to\output.csv

$xml.Save($outputPath)
```

Resulting file should like like this:

```xml
<EmployeeImport>
  <Employee>
    <XRefCode>1234567</XRefCode>
    <EmployeeNumber>1234567</EmployeeNumber>
    <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
    <ContactInformationTypeXrefCode>BusinessEmail</ContactInformationTypeXrefCode>
    <EffectiveStart>04/16/2021</EffectiveStart>
    <IsForSystemCommunication>0</IsForSystemCommunication>
    <ElectronicAddress>Jdoe@Company.com</ElectronicAddress>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <XRefCode>2345678</XRefCode>
    <EmployeeNumber>2345678</EmployeeNumber>
    <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <ContactInformationTypeXrefCode>BusinessEmail</ContactInformationTypeXrefCode>
    <EffectiveStart>04/16/2021</EffectiveStart>
    <IsForSystemCommunication>0</IsForSystemCommunication>
    <ElectronicAddress>Jsmith@Company.com</ElectronicAddress>
  </Employee>
</EmployeeImport>
```

Comment: This is great, you're missing `<ContactInformation>` though

Comment: Love this, on the right path.  Missing what Santiago suggested.  But this is great!

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach on your question, I prefer Mathias solution because it is clean code and this is pretty ugly but serves it's purpose.

```
$csv=@'
XRefCode,EmployeeNumber,FirstName,LastName,ContactInformationTypeXrefCode,EffectiveStart,IsForSystemCommunication,ElectronicAddress
1234567,1234567,Joe,Doe,BusinessEmail,04/16/2021,0,Jdoe@Company.com,
2345678,2345678,Jane,Smith,BusinessEmail,04/16/2021,0,Jsmith@Company.com
'@|ConvertFrom-Csv

$properties=$csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name

[xml]$xml=@"
<EmployeeImport>
$(foreach($line in $csv){
@'
 <Employee>
  <XRefCode>{0}</XRefCode>
  <EmployeeNumber>{1}</EmployeeNumber>
  <FirstName>{2}</FirstName>
  <LastName>{3}</LastName>
    <ContactInformation>
     <ContactInformationTypeXrefCode>{4}</ContactInformationTypeXrefCode>
     <EffectiveStart>{5}</EffectiveStart>
     <IsForSystemCommunication>{6}</IsForSystemCommunication>
     <ElectronicAddress>{7}</ElectronicAddress>
    </ContactInformation>
 </Employee>
'@ -f ($properties|%{$line.$_})
})
</EmployeeImport>
"@
```

[image]

Comment: I have been playing with this a bit and I keep getting the following error:      Error formatting a string: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list..
At line:4 char:1
+ @'
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ( <Employee>
  ...>
 </Employee>:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatError

Comment: The error is related to the data source (your csv) not the code. I'm unable to reproduce this error using the example code I posted. You need to inspect your csv. @Jeff

Comment: Oh, i think i may be on to something.  Forget the last response.  There are 7 properties in the csv, and if using 0, this references to there being 8.  One field is statically "0".  Now I just need to figure out the exporting and I can test.  This is very close!! Thank you

Comment: @Jeff actually there were 8 properties in the csv in your original post, now I see that `IsForSystemCommunication` seem to be removed from your `PSObject`. If you can explain where exactly is the data coming from or give me an actual representation of the input data to be converted to XML I can help you.

Comment: the data is merged data from AD and a cav from HR.  In then end the "IsForSystemCommunication" actually is always 0, so i took that out, which brought the properties down to 7.  This worked.  Then I created and output variable for the location then saved the XML using $xml.Save($Output).  This worked like a charm!  I'm about to submit this for testing.  Thank you so much for this help.  (I dont have enough reputation to add points visually, but I have clicked up arrow!)

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out for you @Jeff

Comment: I'm hoping you can help me again on this real quick.  All of a sudden i get no errors, but i cannot make the XML file anymore.  It run and doesn't give any output at all anymore.  Unsure why.  I check the $xml variable and it's blank.